# Impossible to locate missing files

Tags: blend-files, library

I have a broken links in my blend, i tried to use the "find missing files" operator, however it systematically throw an error messages about missing jpeg or .blends, **not even used in this blend data**, i can confirm that everything is packed except for a few links.

This issue is very strange, blender seems to just skip the search of all other missing files when it encounters any errors

There are 200+ missing links, manually going in the outliner and relocating the libraries will not do the job. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Outliner switch to "Orphan Data" and Delete links from there ...